# Allow empty validation in certain cases

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to validate postalcodes based on database data if it is required for the country or not and which format.

I've currently the following validation rules in the model. The only problem is that if there is no postalcode provided the validation rule is not triggered. Any suggestions?

```
    $validator
        ->requirePresence('postalcode', 'true')
        ->add('postalcode', [
            'shouldHavePostalCode' => [
                'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
                    $countriesTable = TableRegistry::get('Countries');

                    $country = $countriesTable->findByIsoCode($context['data']['country'])->first();

                    if(is_null($country)) {
                        return 'postcode kon niet gecontroleerd worden door ongeldig land';
                    }

                    return $country->need_postalcode;
                },
                'message' => 'Verplicht voor dit land', 
            ],
            'validPostalCode' => [
                'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
                    $countriesTable = TableRegistry::get('Countries');

                    $country = $countriesTable->findByIsoCode($context['data']['country'])->select(['postalcode_format', 'iso_code'])->first();

                    if (empty($country->postalcode_format)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    $zip_regexp = '/^'.$country->postalcode_format.'$/ui';
                    $zip_regexp = str_replace(' ', '( |)', $zip_regexp);
                    $zip_regexp = str_replace('-', '(-|)', $zip_regexp);
                    $zip_regexp = str_replace('N', '[0-9]', $zip_regexp);
                    $zip_regexp = str_replace('L', '[a-zA-Z]', $zip_regexp);
                    $zip_regexp = str_replace('C', $country->iso_code, $zip_regexp);

                    if((bool)preg_match($zip_regexp, $value)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return 'Ongeldige indeling (' . $country->postalcode_format . ')';
                },
            ]
        ])
        ->allowEmpty('postalcode');
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, the following did the trick.

```
->allowEmpty('postalcode', function($context) {
    if(!isset($context['data']['country']) || empty($context['data']['country'])) {
        return true;
    }

    $countriesTable = TableRegistry::get('Countries');

    $country = $countriesTable->findByIsoCode($context['data']['country'])->first();

    if(is_null($country)) {
        return 'postcode kon niet gecontroleerd worden door ongeldig land';
    }

    return !$country->need_postalcode;
}, 'Verplicht');
```